# Different regex output for grep, ack and rubular

Tags: regex, grep, ack

I wanted to test this `(<\/?)+[a-z]+(>)` regex against different tools to see what I would get. Actually the purpose of the experiment was to test how each of the utility displayed results back to console. Basically it searches the below html document and then matches all html tags. To my surprise the result that I got from [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/) and [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) varied significantly. [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) did not even return anything back

Ack

[image]

Grep

[image]

Ag

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        body and so
        df
        s;kl,
        <p>Hello code kit</p>
        <p>Thats pretty great</p>
        <p>Really neat!</p>
        <p>I wanna be a developer for life</p>
        <nav>
             breeee!
        </nav>
        I am in love 
        <p>Ummmmmm!</p>
        wtf
        okay buddy!
        <p>
            I took that shit out
        </p>
        <aside>
            eeem
        </aside>
        Sometimes u really get bored
    </body>
</html>
```

Just for sanity, I went ahead and tested it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/) and viola! the output was just like when I used [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) from the CLI. So my question is why does the result of this simple regex varies based on the tool used

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an extended regular expression for `grep` to work in this case. Add the `-E` flag.  I get pretty much the same output for all three tools in that case:

[image: ack]

[image: ag]

[image: grep]

Comment: Oh, I see. I switched the grep to have a -E flag and it worked. Anyways what color settings are you using for grep. Ack still behaves weird though. matches only half.

Comment: Oh sorry - I forgot I have an alias to add `--color` to `grep`.

Comment: ack "still behaves weird" because of a bug in ack.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations.  You've found a bug in ack.  Apparently ack is colorizing the two capture groups and not the entire matching string.

I've created a bug report for it in GitHub: https://github.com/petdance/ack2/issues/304

Thanks for reporting this, although it wasn't your intent. :-)